# How to export cck field list from Drupal 6 to CSV files for import in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, migrations

I am migrating a D6 site to D7 using migrate_d2d_ui but find that the cck fields for my various content types are not automatically migrated.

I would like to build a csv file containing the D6 cck field structure (name, type, length, #values, help text, etc) so that a csv file can be built for each content type and imported into D7, perhaps using feeds, to build out the full D7 content type and field structure.  Hopefully, migrate_d2d-ui can be mapped to bring over the content once the full D7 structure is built out.

I have investigated Features, Views Data Export, Feeds, Content Copy, and Bundle Copy, but have not found a combination that works with both D6 and D7 platforms.

Any suggestions for creating and importing this csv file or do I need to manually recreate each field in D7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this approach and ended up using the features module because I could not find a complete or workable solution using csv export/import.